# Symfony – “Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string” persisting entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I’m trying to persist an entity with doctrine, the entity has a date attribute and this, apparently, is generating the error.

This is how the attribute is declared in the entity:

```
/**
 * @var date
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="fecha", type="date")
 * @ORM\Id
 */
 private $fecha;
```

And this is how I create the Entity at controller and the code to persist it with doctrine:

```
$estadistica = new EstadisticaTerceros();
$fecha = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d', '2017-05-04');
$estadistica->setFecha($fecha);
//Set other attributes
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($estadistica);
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->flush();
```

In the table the attribute is date type.

And this is the error screen: 
[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that your `fecha` column is not the primary key of the table.  So you can drop the `@ORM\Id` annotation from that column:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="fecha", type="date")
 */
 private $fecha;
```

`date_create_from_format` is also an alias for `DateTime::createFromFormat` and I'd recommend using that just so it's a little more explicit that you are creating a \DateTime:

```
$fecha = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2017-05-04');
```

Comment: It works, i don't know exactly why but thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome.  It works because you should only use the `@ORM\Id` column once in your entity and it should only be on the primary key for that table.  You likely had this here as a duplicate from a copy/paste error.

Comment: And what if I want to use composite primary key? I think this is the cause: "Even in version 2.0 you can have composite keys as long as they only consist of the primitive types integer and string" http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html#primitive-types-only

Comment: That is correct.  You can't have a date that is part of a primary key (which is not something you'd really want to do anyway).

Answer (score 1):

If `$estadistica->setFecha` is expecting a string, just pass it the ISO 8601 date string `'2017-05-04'` directly instead of converting it to a DateTime instance.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have answer for similiar question:

[doctrine DateTime could not be converted to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32678234/doctrine-datetime-could-not-be-converted-to-string)

You should pass the string into Your entity. With DateTime class instance You could do it as follows:

```
$estadistica->setFecha($fecha->format('Y-m-d'));
```